# Unable to retrieve element by id from array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I need your help. I try to make a dynamic page for each object that I have in the file `boxArray`. To extract objects, I created a service called `boxService`I manage to get all the elements, but when I try to extract each individual object by method `getDifferentBox` I get errors that look like this:

`TS2322: Type '<Observable null>;' is not assignable to type 'Observable&lt;IBoxModel&gt;'.<br/>Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'IBoxModel'.`

`TS2345: Argument of type 'IBoxModel | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IBoxModel'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IBoxModel'.`

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much

boxService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, of} from "rxjs";
import {IBoxModel} from "../model/boxModel";
import {boxArray} from "../array/boxArray";

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BoxService {

getBoxes():Observable<IBoxModel[]>{
 return of(boxArray)
}

getDifferentFox(id: string):Observable<IBoxModel> {
 return of<IBoxModel>(boxArray.find( value => value.id === + id ) )
}
}
```

boxArray.ts

```
import {IBoxModel} from "../model/boxModel";

export const boxArray: IBoxModel[] = [
{ id: 1,
  title: "Бокс номер 1",
  address: 0o1515,
}
{ id: 2,
  title: "Бокс номер 2",
  address: 0o1519,
}]
```

boxModel.ts

```
export interface IBoxModel {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  address: number;
}
```

Comment: There is a chance, that `find` will return `undefined` (because there may be no value with the given id). But `of <IBoxModel>` doesn't allow `undefined`. So you have to define, what to do if no element is found ...

Comment: @derpirscher Can you help me to write method retrieve object by id?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your find ...

Comment: But it isn't work... It gives me errors and I can't use this method to go to a single object page

Comment: Because you are not handling the case, when there is no element with the given id ... You have to define what to do when no element is found.

Comment: @derpirscher can you show me how to do it? I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

As **derpirscher** already said there is nothing wrong with your find.
However, you can tweak the data type of your function to resolve the issue. So that when you have no match you will get `undefined` and your method accepts that also.

```
getDifferentFox(id: string): Observable<IBoxModel | undefined> {
   return of<IBoxModel>(boxArray.find((value) => value.id === +id));
}
```

And you should also handle the `undefined` value when you subscribe to the function.

```
this.boxService.getDifferentFox(this.id.toString()).subscribe((res) => {
   this.result = '';
   if (res) {
      this.result = JSON.stringify(res);
   } else {
      alert('No record found');
   }
});
```

Check out the **[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xiw1ke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks, but the fact is that I use Webstorm and these 2 errors show and underline this line: `return of<IBoxModel>(postsArray.find( value => value.id == + id ) )`. Only //@ts-ignore helps to solve this problem but i think it is wrong. How can you comment it?

Comment: In my solution, I showed.
`Observable<IBoxModel | undefined>`